# Bind a new object to an Angular form instead of single properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a very simple interface:

*(models.ts)*

```
export interface User{
Id : number;
FirstName : string;
LastName : string;
Email: string;
PhoneNumber: string;
}
```

And a very simple form:

*(app.component.html)*

```
 <fieldset class='form-group' >
  <h2>Create New User</h2>
  <label>First Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='FirstName'></label><br>
  <label>Last Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='LastName'></label><br>
  <label>Phone number: <input type="phone"[(ngModel)]='PhoneNumber'></label><br>
  <label>Email Address: <input type="email" [(ngModel)]='Email'></label><br>
<button (click)="createNewUser()">Create User</button>
</fieldset>
```

where I 2 way bind my data onto simple strings and then create an object based off these strings. This works, however it feels a bit messy, I was wondering if it's possible to new up an empty object and then assign them directly to the object like this:

*(app.component.ts)*

```
 userToCreate: User;
```

*(app.component.html)*

```
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='userToCreate.FirstName'></label><br>
```

When I try to do this, TypeScript throws an error saying it

> Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined

What am i doing wrong, or is this not possible?

Comment: Just use `userToCreate = User;`

Comment: And do you actually set ` userToCreate` value to anything?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, when i try that, Typescript errors and says 'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Comment: @MrGiggles, do you also a class called `User` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `userToCreate` is `undefined` and thus has none of the properties you are binding to.

You either need to bind to individual properties of your component and then assemble the user object in your `createNewUser` function; or you need to initialize your `userToCreate` with at least an empty object.

```
userToCreate: User = {} as User;
```

The type assertion (also known as cast) is needed because `{}` doesn't actually define the properties the `User` interface requires (since none of them are optional).

Comment: Thanks, thats fixed it, I knew it would be something simple

Comment: You should strongly consider turning `User` into an actual class that you instantiate with `userToCreate: User = new User()` instead, though. Doing this here breaks typing a little because you don't actually know that any of the `User` properties will actually be set. Likely this has no consequence in this case, but it's not entirely clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would offer you to consider using reactive forms with form builder, so you could:

1. Better manipulate your inputs;
2. Add validation;
3. And also you could use NgOnSubmit on your button;

[Reactive forms docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Also, I believe that your problem with undefined object will be solved as you will be able to add typings and default values in form builder.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look